# SSRS Device info configuration changes ignored

Tags: reporting-services

Running SQL Server 2008 (not R2).

I have a few reports that have URLs as actions on charts and textboxes which are renedered in HTML within a reportviewer control. When the links are selected they are opened in a new tab (or window), and I would like them to be opened in the existing frame that contains the reportviewer control. I have done some reading on the two methods to resolving this issue: (1) setting the target in the URL or using javascript, AND (2) updating the LinkTarget device info configuration parameter in rsreportserver.config. I have decided to go with option (2)

After updating rsreportserver.config with the following, I find that there is no change to the target value of the link in the rendered report. I keep getting _top as a target.

```
<RENDER>
...
<Extension Name="HTML4.0" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.Html40RenderingExtension,Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering" Visible="False" LogAllExecutionRequests="False">
         <Configuration>
            <DeviceInfo>
               <LinkTarget>_self</LinkTarget>                  
            </DeviceInfo>
         </Configuration>
      </Extension>
...
</RENDER>
```

It appears that these changes are ignored by SSRS when rendering the report in the reportviewer control.

Has anyone come across this issue? Any solutions?

Comment: I also have this problem. Have you tried placing `<DeviceInfo>` directly under `<Extension ...>`? Just a thought....

Comment: @Roatin:  I have tried it without the configuration tags, and it still appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it appears that using the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395(v=sql.100).aspx) for the rsreportserver.config file device info section didn't work for me.

After digging I found that if I set the ReportViewer Control HyperLinkTarget parameter to "_self" it corrects the issue, and my URLs now appear within the frame. Here is a snapshot:

```
<rs:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote"
        SizeToReportContent="true"
        ShowParameterPrompts="false"
        ShowToolBar="false"
        ShowPageNavigationControls="false"
        ShowCredentialPrompts="false"
        ShowFindControls="false"
        ShowRefreshButton="false"
        ShowWaitControlCancelLink="false"
        ShowZoomControl="false"
        ShowPrintButton="false"
        HyperlinkTarget ="_self">
    </rs:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles onto question as I did, and you are looking to remove `target="_top"` from your "Go to URL" links in SSRS, the following works for SSRS 2019.

Modify

\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx

And change the RS tag from:

`<RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server"/>`

to

`<RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" HyperlinkTarget ="_self"/>`